# collective.googleanalytics 'No Analytics account was found for the currently logged-in user.'

Tags: plone

I'm on Plone 4.0.1 and I'm trying to use c.googleanalytics 1.1.

Following the docs I registered my domain on google accounts and I got my "OAuth Consumer Key" and "OAuth Consumer Secret".

Now, every time I try to access the portal (no matter the user) I get this:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 127, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 47, in call_object
  Module zope.formlib.form, line 782, in __call__
  Module five.formlib.formbase, line 50, in update
  Module zope.formlib.form, line 745, in update
  Module plone.fieldsets.form, line 24, in setUpWidgets
  Module zope.formlib.form, line 384, in setUpEditWidgets
  Module zope.schema._field, line 291, in bind
  Module Products.Five.schema, line 36, in get
  Module collective.googleanalytics.vocabularies, line 45, in getWebProperties
  Module plone.memoize.volatile, line 276, in replacement
  Module collective.googleanalytics.utility, line 213, in getAccountsFeed
  Module collective.googleanalytics.utility, line 172, in makeClientRequest
  Module gdata.analytics.service, line 97, in GetAccountList
  Module gdata.analytics.service, line 77, in QueryAccountListFeed
  Module gdata.service, line 1097, in Get
  Module gdata.service, line 1108, in Get
RequestError: {'status': 403, 'body': 'No Analytics account was found for the currently logged-in user.', 'reason': 'Forbidden'}
```

How it's supposed to work if I cannot insert my authentication data?

I see in

collective.googleanalytics-1.1-py2.6.egg/collective/googleanalytics/interfaces/utility.py

that there is a field "auth_token" so I suppose that something must be filled in... but that's impossible because the above mentioned error does not allow to get the form.

Thank in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're getting a bad AuthSub token, perhaps by authorizing using a non-Google account:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-analytics-data-export-api/browse_thread/thread/712abe41ad57095b/363bb2aa1db308fd

I've opened a bug report in the collective.googleanalytics issue tracker:

http://plone.org/products/collective.googleanalytics/issues/9/view

Please follow up with me there so that we can get this resolved. Thanks!